# Laravel Eloquent Relationship - Inserting data into multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have the following structure:

3 tables: movies, actors, genres

**Movies Table Schema:**

```
Schema::create('movies', function (Blueprint $t) {
        $t->increments('id');
        $t->string('title');
        $t->integer('genre_id')->unsigned();
        $t->foreign('genre_id')->references('id')->on('genres');
        $t->string('genre');
        $t->timestamps();
    });
```

**Genres Table Schema:**

```
Schema::create('genres', function (Blueprint $t) {
        $t->increments('id');
        $t->string('name');
        $t->timestamps();
    });
```

**Actors Table Schema:**

```
Schema::create('actors', function (Blueprint $t) {
        $t->increments('id');
        $t->string('name');
        $t->timestamps();
    });
```

**Movie Modal:**

```
public function genre()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Genre');
}
public function actor()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Actor');
    }
```

**Genre Modal:**

```
public function movie()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Movie');
}
```

**Actor Modal:**

```
public function movie()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Movie');
}
```

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('movies.insert') }}">
   <input type="text" name="movieName" id="movieName">
   <input type="text" name="actorName" id="actorName">
   <input type="text" name="genre" id="genre">
   <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

I am using the following controller method to post data from the form and everything is working fine but when I submit 2 movies with the same Genre, example "Action/Drama", I am getting 2 separate entries in the genres table like:

id: 1
name: Action/Drama

id: 2
name: Action/Drama

What is the best method to use a single id for a specific genre type over and over again? For example, if I add 10 movies with genre type 'Action/Drama', then the 'genre_id' foreign key in the 'movies' table should only show one specific id which corresponds with the genres table's 'Action/Drama' Id. Hope that makes sense :/

**Controller Method:**

```
public function addMovies(Request $request)
{
    $genre = new Genre;
    $genre->name = $request->input('genre');
    $genre->save();

    $movie = new Movie;
    $movie->title = $request->input('movieName');
    $movie->genre = $request->input('genre');
    $movie->genre()->associate($genre);
    $movie->save();

    $actor = new Actor;
    $actor->name = $request->input('actorName');
    $actor->save();
    $actor->movie()->save($movie);

    return redirect()->route('movies.search');
}
```

**The output table should look something like this:**

[image]

Note: I also have a pivot table which is connecting movies with actors to facilitate the many-to-many relation, but I haven't included it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you are explicitly saving a new genre every time that's why you're getting duplicates. What you want to do is something like

```
$genre = Genre::firstOrCreate("name", $request->input('genre'));
```

Then you'd assign the movie to the genre

Comment: Awesome sauce! I've changed both genre and actor logic to firstOrCreate. Does this mean I can use firstOrNew method for creating a new movie? Meaning if a movie already exists in the database it should not be repeated?

Comment: Correct, if you do not want duplicate movie titles I would take the same approach.